# Format of date-fields and calendar

Tags: ms-access

I have a problem with date-fields in access forms and tables.

Despite having my region settings set to germany-locale (format is DD.MM.YYYY), the calendar-look in access changes to something 'gibberish'/indish ? I really don't know, why it shows this. My Office and my Windows Install are all originally set to German, so there ain't be a chance with custom/other region settings.

Until now, i have circumvent this problem by not showing the calendar. What really gives me a headache is, that i can't specify specific dates, which should exist e.g the 31st of december ?? December ends in this calendar on 29st??

So, does have anyone a clue about what's going on here?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can override the regional setting language in office when going into the menu File > Options > Language

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook-help/change-the-default-language-for-office-programs-HA010356057.aspx

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, choosing another language didn't help, i did try this by changing to en-gb, en-us and back to ger-ger. The language settings isn't the really problem here, i could live with that. What's really problematic is that there aren't some dates available, that should be...